# Default logging file for spring boot application

Tags: logging, spring-boot

I have set the logging level in the spring boot application in `application.yml` like this:

```
logging.level.com.Myapplicationname=DEBUG
```

The application is packaged and deployed as war on tomcat. Apart from this I haven't set the `logback.xml` to define the log file etc.

Where can I see the console logs when some user uses the application over the browser?

Is there any default file created by framework?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

## Prior to Spring-Boot 2.3.x

You should either specify `logging.file` or `logging.path`, but not both (
when both are specified, `logging.path` is ignored and only `logging.file` is considered).

**1. Using logging.file**

You may use `logging.file` one of the following way:

```
logging.file = logfile.log                     //in current folder
logging.file = relativepath/to/logfile.log     //relative path with filename
logging.file = /fullpath/to/logfile.log        //full path with filename
```

In [Spring Boot Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging-file-output):

> By default, Spring Boot will only log to the console and will not
> write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the
> console output you need to set a logging.file or logging.path property
> (for example in your application.properties).

In [Spring Boot's how to logging doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html):

> If the only change you need to make to logging is to set the levels of
> various loggers then you can do that in application.properties using
> the "logging.level" prefix, e.g.
> You can also set the location of a file to log to (in addition to the
> console) using "logging.file".

**2. Using logging.path**

You could also use `logging.path` to set the path, in which case the logfile will automatically be named `spring.log`:

```
logging.path = ./                         // -> spring.log in current folder
logging.path = relativepath/to/logs       // -> relativepath/to/logs/spring.log
logging.path = /fullpath/to/logs          // -> /fullpath/to/logs/spring.log
```

In [Spring Boot doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html):

> [*Using logging.path*] Writes spring.log to the specified directory.
> Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

[springframework.guru on Spring Boot logging](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/):

> There is also a logging.path property to specify a path for a logging
> file. If you use it, Spring Boot creates a spring.log file in the
> specified path. However, you cannot specify both the logging.file and
> logging.path properties together. If done, Spring Boot will ignore
> both.

## Since Spring-Boot 2.3.x

The previously used properties `logging.file` or `logging.path` became deprecated in Spring-Boot 2.2.x and were replaced in version 2.3.x with `logging.file.name` and `logging.file.path`.

See [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging.logback).

Comment: logging.file was deprecated and renamed to logging.file.name in 2.2. It was then removed in 2.3.

Answer (score 51):

for those who are using spring boot 2.2.x you need to put this in configuration file

```
logging.file.name='/var/log/app.log'
```

or use this

```
logging.file.path='/var/log'
```

note that if you use logging.file.path it will writes **spring.log** to the specified directory. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory

Comment: No need to use ticks here but thanks for pointing the difference in spring boot 2.2.x out.

Answer (score 20):

The latest spring release has changed a bit, now we have to use:

> logging.file.name

Instead of using this (which is the old way)

> logging.file

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 8):

As alexbt said, you cannot use both properties at the same time (logging.path and logging.file) because Spring Boot will ignore both.

But you can use logging.file with a path encoded.

Example:
logging.file=/path/to/logs/your_logfile.log

Answer (score 0):

for spring boot 2.3.X, if deploy application in windows,you can use bellow config. that `E` is drive name.`logging.file.name=E:\\A\\B\\C\\log-file.log`
or `logging.file.name=E:/A/B/C/log-file.log`