# View SprintBoot log file via Intellij

Tags: spring-boot

I'm running a spring boot application via intellij

Where the log would be stored by default? How to view the same in Spring Boot?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default logging file for spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158191/default-logging-file-for-spring-boot-application)

Comment: I don't see any file as logging.file in my project. Do we need to create that file? In which directory i need? In general most of them projects are builded via Ant or Maven or Sbt

Comment: No. You need to write properties to the file. (src/main/resources/application.properties)