# customize log file name from code in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, logback

I have a simple springboot application with rest end points. Every time I call the rest end point, it performs a certain activity. Right now, all the logging information goes to server.log file in wildfly. I would like to have a scenario where i can customize the name of the log file everytime my rest end points are invoked. For e.g.

All logging information from point A to Point B shall goto a file called First.log and all the logging information from point B to Point C shall goto Second.log

Is such an implementation possible either by using logback or log4j2. can i customize the name of the log file from code where in I specify every logging information from this point on should go to a specific file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default logging file for spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39158191/default-logging-file-for-spring-boot-application)

Comment: Hi Piotr. thanks for the response. I see that the log file name can be specified in application.properties. I would like to change the name of the log file from the code. For e.g When method A is invoked all the subsequent logs should goto A.log and when method b is invoked all the subsequent logs should goto B.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Log4j2, you can reconfigure it at runtime with [`Configurator#reconfigure`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html#reconfigure-java.net.URI--).

The standard `log4j2.xml` file used by Spring Boot (cf. [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2-file.xml)) uses the Java system property `LOG_FILE` to store the location of the log file. Therefore you just need to:

- configure Spring Boot to log to a file (cf. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.file-output)). For example you can add:

  ```
  logging.file.name = initial.log
  ```

  to your `application.properties,
- whenever you want to change the name of the log file call

  ```java
  System.setProperty("LOG_FILE", "first.log");
  Configurator.reconfigure();
  ```

Log4j2 guarantees you that no message will be lost during reconfiguration (the old file is closed *after* the new one has been created).

There is certainly a similar solution for Logback, but Logback can lose messages during reconfiguration.

Comment: This looks closer to what i want to achieve. Thanks for the detailed explanation.